# Azure file share not getting mounted to the pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-files

I am trying to mount azure file share t the kubernetes pod but getting error as follows:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From                           Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled              12s               default-scheduler              Successfully assigned azurepod to k8s-agent-e90e3bbe-0
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  12s               kubelet, k8s-agent-e90e3bbe-0  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-6v6lb"
  Warning  FailedMount            4s (x5 over 12s)  kubelet, k8s-agent-e90e3bbe-0  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azure" : mount failed: exitstatus 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: //006ujp7qo4bhmfmagnt0.file.core.windows.net/persistshare /var/lib/kubelet/pods/64dadbe9-dff0-11e7-a005-000d3a279b90/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/azure cifs [vers=3.0,username=006ujp7qo4bhmfmagnt0,password=key1,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777]
Output: mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Please find below yaml file which I used to create the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: azurepod
spec:
 containers:
  - image: kubernetes/pause
    name: azure
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
 volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: persistshare
      readOnly: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access denied error typically indicates that the issues is with your account. Kubernetes needs credentials to access the file share. These credentials are stored in a Kubernetes secret, which is referenced when creating a Kubernetes pod.
When creating a Kubernetes secret, the secret values must be base64 encoded.
If you haven’t done this already, create Kubernetes secret exactly as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files#create-kubernetes-secret), first encode the name of the storage account. If needed, replace $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME with the name of the Azure storage account and let us know how it goes.**

As a side note: Currently AKS does not support Windows containers.
to accomplish this, you need to deploy a Windows Kubernetes cluster using ACS Engine. ACS Engine - https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine
With this in place, here are instructions on setting up a volume using an Azure disk:https://github.com/andyzhangx/Demo/tree/master/windows/azuredisk

Comment: Thnx a lotttttt